# ServiceStack ToPostUrl() extension method ignores virtual directories

Tags: servicestack-razor

I'm using ServiceStack.Razor C# in Visual Studio 2015 for a small internal project and am working (learning) from the sample projects. As part of my development, I host all of my websites and apis etc in virtual directories, so rather than

localhost/hello

i have

localhost/SomeProject/hello

The problem is however, that once the razor is being delivered from the virtual directory /SomeProject/ , the ToPostUrl() extension method creates an absolute path and so the logic fails:

```
<form action="@(new Hello().ToPostUrl())">
```

results in

```
<form action="/hello">
```

which breaks the redirect when the form is submitted. What is the correct way to handle this? A virtual directory doesn't seem like a particularly unusual use-case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's Reverse routing only resolves paths from ServiceStack's Route definitions.

You'll need to include the prefix to any custom paths/virtual directory where ServiceStack is mounted before the route.

Comment: I think this makes the reverse routing not as useful as it should have been. From my point of view, using reverse routing everywhere should guarantee that you could rename services (and their routes), including a custom path such as "api", without modification. If I understand correctly, one would now have to go through all .cshtml files, and append the /path/ before the reverse lookup anyway.

Comment: @specimen reverse routing is a client library feature that's also used by the Service Clients to generate the appropriate route, it doesn't have a dependency to your server AppHost to know about your server handler mapping